# navigator.getUserMedia mutes (partially) the other sounds of the computer

Tags: javascript, firefox, windows-7, getusermedia

`navigator.getUserMedia` mutes (partially) the other sounds of the computer.
What can I do to make it not happen? Some additional parameter?

Comment: Could you try to explain another way? I'm not understanding what "dims the control computer" means.

Comment: Also you should assume that we don't speak the language of your title (polish?), and translate that too.

Comment: What browser/os are you seeing this on?

Comment: More understandable?
I completed.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not entirely clear to me, but I'm going to venture a guess about what's going on...

Unless you are wearing a headset, most microphones pick up the sound emitted by your system, which, depending on where it is output, can feedback quite badly. For this reason, getUserMedia implements **echo cancellation** by default, which is quite desirable for uses like WebRTC calls.

Unfortunately, Firefox does not currently have a way to turn this off, but this is [being worked on](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=987186). *Once this is fixed*, then the standard way to disable it should work, which would be to pass in an `{ audio: { echoCancellation: false } }` constraint to `getUserMedia()`.

To verify if this is your problem, try going to about:config and setting `media.getusermedia.aec_enabled` to `false`.

If this does not match your symptoms, then please elaborate.

Comment: Did Not. That's not it.
The idea is that the sound example of foobar2000 is muted during recording.
I want to not mute.